# Symfony custom method repository not able to access in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have two database connections in symfony. I have created a method in repository and tried to access that method in controller. But, I am not able to access that method,and I get an error (undefined method getSuitelog()) Please let me know how to access the queries and method from repository in controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Testing;

use App\Entity\Testing\CpSelection;
use App\Entity\Testing\CpTests;
use App\Repository\CpSelectionRepository;
use App\Repository\CpTestsRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class TestingController extends AbstractController
{
    
    #[Route('/testing/id/{{id}}', name: 'index')]
    public function CpTestSuit($id): Response
    {
        // $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.testing_entity_manager');
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager('testing');
        $cpsuit =  $repository->getRepository(CpSelection::class, 'CpSelection')
                    ->getSuitelog($id);
        $cpTests = $repository->getRepository(CpTests::class, 'CpTests')
                    ->findAll(); //

        return $this->render('testing/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'TestingController',
            'suite' => $cpsuit, 
            'tests' => $cpTests,
        ]);
        
    }
```

Repository with getSuitelog method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Testing\CpSelection;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method CpSelection|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method CpSelection|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method CpSelection[]    findAll()
 * @method CpSelection[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CpSelectionRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CpSelection::class);
    }

    
    public function getSuitelog($suite_id = NULL) {

        $where = "";
        $values = array ();
        if ($suite_id != NULL) {
            $where = " where id = ? ";
            $values = array (1 => $suite_id);
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM App:CpSelection" . $where;
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                $query
            )
            ->execute()
            ->getArrayResult();

    }
```

My Entity class looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Testing;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CpSelection
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CpSelectionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="cp_selection")
 */
class CpSelection
{
......
}
```

Comment: If you have created a custom repository, just inject it as a parameter into your controller action. Repositories returned from `$entityManager->getRepository()` are auto-generated based on given entity name, i.e. the result is not an instance of your custom repository.

Comment: Do you have `repositoryClass` annotation in your entity class? 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

Comment: This sort of thing typically indicates that you did not properly map your repository to the entity.  Doctrine creates a default repository if the mapping is not done correctly.  You can check the class returned by getRepository just to confirm this is the problem.  And then review your mapping.

Comment: Couple of more off-topic observations.  1. getManager returns an entity manager.  Calling it $repository works but it's makes your code harder to follow.  2. getRepository takes exactly one argument.  The second argument agains make your code harder to follow. 3. Your getTest query is poorly written and leaves you open to sql injections. You really should consider working your way through some of the examples in the docs.  Doing so will probably save you time in the longer term.

Comment: Please share more details. You are not calling `getSuitelog` anywhere in the given code, so it cannot throw such an error

Comment: @Nico, previously i used the name getTest and then i changed to getSuitelog. I have updated the code now.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you tried dumping the class type of `$repository->getRepository(CpSelection::class, 'CpSelection')` to see whether the repository is returned properly? Also, how does the configuration for your entity manager, and for the entity itself, look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom repository injection example:

```
#[Route('/testing/id/{{id}}', name: 'index')]
public function CpTestSuit($id, CpSelectionRepository $myCustomRepository): Response 
{
...
}
```

**Update:**
To get this work we should use autowiring (is enabled by default in symfony DI-container) and rewrite repository so that it do not extend  any basic repository. Instead, inject EntityManager into Repository constructor, and then inject this concrete repository into controller action. If you type-hint arguments, symfony autowiring will do all other job.

Details are explained here https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/

Comment: Does not actually answer the question and probably would not work in this case anyways.

Comment: Don't mean to be stalking you but your explanation about which repository class to extend is a bit incoherent and probably wrong.  The ServiceEntityRepository shown in the question is specifically designed for autowiring and is usually the correct choice.  And again it is not actually causing the problem indicated in the question.  Improper wiring would have generated completely different error messages.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, didn't know that ServiceEntityRepository is a special thing. But still don't understand why do you suppose that just injecting repository in the action will not work. Would you please explain?

Comment: The main idea of mine was that the repo should be registered and injected as a service, as this is more clean and clear approach than retrieving it via entityManager.

Comment: We still have not heard back from the original poster but by far the most likely problem here is that the repository class is not properly linked to the entity.  You can argue that injecting a repo is better than pulling it from the entity manager but that it is not the issue here.

Comment: Got it. You are right, I offered another way, which is just not prone to such error )

Comment: I should have also mentioned that it is entirely possible that their code is working and that the 'message' is coming from the IDE.  The IDE expects an EntityRepository and will complain when a custom method is invoked.  In which case, your approach will indeed work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestions. I tried injecting repository directly into controller....but  the same error "Undefined method "getSuitelog". The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy!".

Comment: I have added the updated code in answers......please check and let me know how to update the code. Thanks!

Comment: @pramod, did you add a new method "getSuitelog" to the repository? Please show updated code of repository too.

Comment: I just updated the name getTest to getSuitelog.                                                        
public function getSuitelog($suite_id = NULL) {

        $where = "";
        $values = array ();
        if ($suite_id != NULL) {
            $where = " where id = ? ";
            $values = array (1 => $suite_id);
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM App:CpSelection" . $where;
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                $query
            )
            ->execute()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }